# echarts, 2 marker points shared same cell and overlapped

Tags: angular, marker, echarts

I'm using echarts heatmap. I have the axes value from 0 to 5
And I have a list of items showing them in the heat map as rectangles on the heatmap using mark points:
for each item in the list I create this markerPoint:

```
mp=
{
name: item.name,
xAxis: item.xVal,
yAxis: item.yVal,
symbol: 'rect',
symbolSize:40,
large:false,
itemStyle: {
color: 'black', margin:3
},
label:{
show: true,
formatter: item.name,
itemStyle:{color:'white'}},
};
```

the problem is, if 2 items or more, have close values of x and y, will share the same cell, and will become above each others

```
item1: x:1.5, y:2
item2: x:2, y:2
```

[image: item two above item one]

what I want is something like the following image, the marker point takes left, right or top of the cell.
[image: what I'm looking for]

I tried properties like (position or margin) but nothing worked. I tried also in the live demo of this echarts example that they're using marker points in it:
[example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-marker)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is : symbolOffset: [0, -20]